# How to describe relations between objects unambiguously?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Following Martha's advise I am splitting up a question [Compound sentences, the punctuation and mooore](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4385/compound-sentences-the-punctuation-and-mooore).

Consider the following fragment:

> child nodes of a story representing its sub categories

I intended this fragment for anyone to understand that a story has sub categories, and these sub categories are displayed as child nodes.

1. Is the relation between child nodes, sub categories and a story clear and unambiguous?
2. How else could I construct the fragment so that it could be used as a subject of a sentence?

The story and the sub category are just terms, which may not make any sense to you but they do for those whom it's designated to.

Comment: The prefix "sub" is normally followed by a hyphen, or prepended without a hyphen or space, i.e. "sub-category" or "subcategory".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would prefer

> child nodes representing a story's sub-categories

or maybe something like

> child nodes of a story representing this story's sub-categories

In your construction "representing" could refer back to "a story".

But more likely I would not use this phrase like this. Rather I would introduce child nodes in a dedicated sentence and refer back to the definition:

> A story has sub-categories, and these categories are displayed as child nodes.
>
> *aforementioned child nodes* or even only *child nodes*

Comment: The prefix "sub" is normally followed by a hyphen, or prepended without a hyphen or space, i.e. "sub-category" or "subcategory".

Comment: @Steve - thank you. Maybe direct this comment to the OP too?

Comment: While more sentences almost always provides less ambiguity, comparing the question with his previous one (on making compound sentences), I believe that the first two examples would suit him better than the third.